# renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync Ignores Image on UserContol

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, rendertargetbitmap

I have a UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="taskcard"
x:Class="AYOS_IDPrinter_UWP.TaskCard"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AYOS_IDPrinter_UWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RequestedTheme="Default" Width="486" Height="306">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AuSupportColor" Color="#FFE5C97C"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" RequestedTheme="Default">
    <Grid x:Name="Skeleton" Margin="10,10,10,10" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AuSupportColor}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="NeedleArea"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AuSupportColor}" Background="{StaticResource AUColor}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Label" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="İğne Alanı / Needle Area" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Noto Sans" FontWeight="Normal" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,4,0,5"/>

        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Datas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="Name_Task_Area" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="NameText" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" Text="BERK BABADOĞAN" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TaskText" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Salon Başkanı" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="InfoArea" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SpecsH_1" Margin="0,0,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sınav Yeri / Exam Area: " Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SpecsH_2" Margin="0,0,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Salon Adı / Hall Name:" Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SpecsH_3" Margin="0,0,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Salon No / Hall Number:" Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AreaText" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="İstanbul" Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="HallNameText" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="A Blok 3. Kat Derslik 316" Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="HallNoText" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="340111" Foreground="#FF343434" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="HeaderArea" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="70" Source="Assets/AUSmall.png"/>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="70" Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/AnkudemSmall.png"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Header_1" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="AYÖS" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF284985" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Header_2" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SINAV GÖREV KARTI" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF284985" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Header_3" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="EXAMINATION TASK CARD" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF284985" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Noto Sans" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DateText" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF284985" Text="28 Mayıs 2016 – May 28, 2016" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Noto Sans" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>


    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

I initialize it by this way:

```
 //Initializing task card.
                var item = new TaskCard(Name_TextBox.Text.ToUpper() + " " + Surname_TextBox.Text.ToUpper(), Task_TextBox.Text, ExamArea_TextBox.Text, HallName_TextBox.Text, HallNumber_TextBox.Text, DateConverter.Get(Date_Picker.Date.ToString())); // Creating card.
```

After that, as you knew, we must display UserControl on anything for using the renderTargetBitmap is needed.So, I prepared a grid for showing the UserControl.

```
  <Grid x:Name="RingWaiter_Grid"  BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseHighRevealBorderBrush}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" RequestedTheme="Default" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="RingWaiter_SecondRow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LoadValue_Ring" Text="Lütfen bekleyin..." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="10,0,10,0" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                    <ProgressRing x:Name="Waiter_Ring" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource AndroidGreen}" IsActive="True" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                </Grid>
                <Frame x:Name="ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="486" Height="306"/>
            </Grid>



 //Converting UIelement to Rendered Bitmap

                    ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter.Content = item; // Adding card to canvas.

                    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();

                    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter); // Render frame.
                    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
```

Finally, you can see two Image element in my usercontrol. It looks perfectly after binding it to the Frame. However, when I exported it to a image with FileSavePicker and BitmapEncoder, those Image elements in my user controls randomly appear and disappeared. If I try to export all of the **WaiterGrid**, Image controls stands in its native place. I could not figure out. Could you help me? Thank you.

**Usercontrol on grid:**

[image]

**Exported Image**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I exported it to a image with FileSavePicker and BitmapEncoder, those Image elements in my user controls randomly appear and disappeared

This is caused by no enough time for the images to load. As soon as you add the UserControl `taskcard` to the frame, you render the frame immediately. But when rendering the `ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter` in that time the images are not loaded completed so that images will not be rendered. Add `Task.Delay` to waiting for a while you will find it work well.

```
ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter.Content = item; // Adding card to canvas. 
await Task.Delay(1000);
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ItemAddFrame_RingWaiter); // Render frame.
imgshow.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

`Task.Delay` can help know the reason but is not a good solution. In your previous thread you could see that in my answer I add the `UserControl` in XAML by code like follows:

```
<local:taskcard
    x:Name="elementToRender"
    Width="300"
    Height="350" />
```

If adding the `UserControl` by this way, the above issue may not appear. I'm not sure why you add the control code behind, if you do want to add the control code behind, try to monitor the `Image_Loaded` event handle from your `UserControl` inside.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, @Sunteen Wu - MSFT :) I use Task.Delay() occasionally, but I have never thought of it here ... I must add user control in code behind, because app generates an unique task ID card based on given datas. It have fully - automatized mechanis which gathers data from an Excel file.